# How to get next consecutive similar tag in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like following code in HTML which is generated from some of plugins.

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>item1</span>
  <input type="hidden"></input>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span class="active">item3</span>
  <input type="hidden"></input>
  <input type="hidden"></input>
  <span>item5</span>
  <input type="hidden"></input>
  <span>item6</span>
  <input type="hidden"></input>
</div>
```

I have at top "move up" and "move down" button and by click on it will move span either up or down.

Now what i want, from any of the selected/active span I need next span tag. when i am using `$(this).next()` then it give me hidden input, when I use `$(this).next("span")` then it not give me next span.

so what should be jquery snippet to get from selected span i can get either next or previous similar tag (eg. span in my case)?

Update:
This is the Jquery code I am using

```
$('.btn-move-up').click(function () {
       var $current = $('.parent > span.active');       
       var $prev = $current.prev();    
            $prev.before($current);
        });
$('.btn-move-down').click(function () {
     var $current = $('.parent > span.active');                       
     var $next = $current.next();
     $next.after($current);         
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include all the relevant code, up down, and your jquery attempt to create this.

Comment: Where is your code? We can't debug something we can't see. However it sounds like you need `nextAll('span').first()` or `prevAll('span').first()`

Comment: you can use $(this).next().next() so it with skip the immediate hidden element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, your solution solve my problem

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` and `prev()` alone won't work given your HTML structure as the `span` elements are not always direct siblings.

To fix this you can use `nextAll('span').first()` and `prevAll('span').first()`:

```js
$('.btn-move-up').click(function() {
  var $current = $('.parent > span.active');
  var $prev = $current.prevAll('span').first();
  $prev.before($current);
});

$('.btn-move-down').click(function() {
  var $current = $('.parent > span.active');
  var $next = $current.nextAll('span').first();
  $next.after($current);
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <span>item1</span>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <span>item2</span>
  <span class="active">item3</span>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <span>item5</span>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <span>item6</span>
  <input type="hidden" />
</div>

<button class="btn-move-up">Up</button>
<button class="btn-move-down">Down</button>
```